# Percentage table height and IE9

Tags: html, internet-explorer, height

I have a very stupid problem: I want a field inside a table, which has 100% of the Table-Cell height. The Problem is the IE-Browser, which won't do that. On Chrome etc. it works (Firefox too I think). Here is a sample html-File:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Test</title>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
body {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Verdana, "Verdana CE",  Arial, "Arial CE", "Lucida Grande CE", lucida, "Helvetica CE", sans-serif;
    color: #000000;

    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: medium none;
}

table.subTable td  {
    border-width: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 2px;
}

.ui-slottable table {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

.ui-slottable-slot {
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px; 
    border-width:1px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color: #cccccc;
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    border-collapse: separate;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="ui-slottable">
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="ui-slottable-slot">

                            <table class="subTable" style="margin:2px;">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>T1 Hallo</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>

                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="ui-slottable-slot">

                            <table class="subTable">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>T2 Hallo</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Halloggggggggggggggggggg</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>

                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

In this File The Field T1 should have the same height as T2.

I've tested a lot of different way's, but nothing worked...

Hope someone can tell me how IE makes this...

Comment: Just as a note, embedding tables in tables is bad practice: http://webdesign.about.com/od/layout/a/aa111102a.htm

Comment: This here was just an example.

Comment: Ah okay. If you have some specific code that you need help with, it might be more beneficial. As it currently stands, I have no idea how to sort your problem! Sorry.

Comment: The fields (grey areas) are different height on IE8 and Opera 11.6, too.

Comment: Specific code is difficult, because this is part of a JSF-Page (Very simplified output). But the Problem is the same... With fixed height in the slot they have the same height. But fixed height is not nice...

Answer (score 1):

Attempting to set height usually does not work.

You can get the same height for the fields by using 2 lines in the innermost table for T1, too. (Use nbsp as contents of the extra line.) Then remove the `style="margin:2px;"` inside the table html tag.

Comment: This is the same way as setting the height to a fixed value, which works. But fixing it is not nice... Maybe I must write a workaround...